# Special characters in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a pattern which looks like this (I'm not the creator):

```
[a-z,A-z,0-9,\-,\+,\&,\/,\\\,\s]{1,127}
```

which i pass to [Regex.IsMatch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4.aspx).

Is there a "better" way of writing the same expression? And by better I mean shorter.

And if I would like to add a special character like `æ`, do I simply add `\æ`?

Comment: That regular expression is .. dubious. Anyway, it is equivalent to: `[-.,+&/\\\sA-z]{1,127}`. 1) Removed duplicates (which are meaningless in a character class) 2) Put - at start (which removes it's special meaning) 3) Removed unnecessary escapes 4) Removed range overlap (A-z is different than A-Z and overlaps a-z).

Comment: That's a bizarre Regex. It duplicates `.` and `,` multiple times, and I'm not sure if those characters were intended to be allowed. Also `A-z` gets some unintended characters, or maybe intended characters...nobody can know without a comment.

Comment: it is a very strange regexp, not an expert in C# but i think that using \ in class `[]` is not necessary unless when escaping `]`or using metaclass like `\s` also the repeated usage of `.` and `,` seems to me to useless unless to facilitate reading. comma are not needed separators in class `[]`... actually unless some kind of strange facilitation for reading... but weird...

Comment: @user7116 The dots should be commas, my bad.

Comment: @user2468222 I removed the dots. This is what it really looks like.

Comment: @Johan Then remove the dot in my equivalent rewrite - the other points stand. At this point, I would go back to the *requirements* to see what *should* be matched.

Comment: @user2246674 Ok, is `[-.,+&wæøå/\\\sA-z]{1,127}` correct if I want to add the special characters?

Comment: @user2246674 don't you miss `a-z` if case if not specifically ignored? edit: ok, i miss the cap A small z... sorry.

Comment: @user2468222 A-z is covers *all* characters between A and z: [A-Z, \[, \ , ^, _, `, \], a-z](http://www.asciitable.com). The insensitivity is applied during the match after the character class range is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by removing the duplicates. This includes the repeated commas, as well as the `a-z` because this is encapsulated in the `A-z` range, as is the `\`.

You also do not have to escape most characters, and you can pull the `-` to the front of the character class to avoid escaping that one too.

This leaves you with:

```
[-+&/,A-z0-9\s]{1,127}
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to add  the characters"æ ø å"? `[-+&/æøå,A-z0-9\s]{1,127}`?

Comment: @Johan What about other Unicode characters from different languages?

Comment: @user2246674 Is it even possible to make a generic regex for that?

Comment: @Johan You may be interested in [Unicode Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CategoryOrBlock) - i.e. `\p{Lu}` (case insensitive) matches all letters; English, Swedish, or otherwise.

Comment: @Johan Yes you just add whatever else you want to match into the class, although honestly I think it's time to go back to the *requirement* and see what you're trying to match.

Comment: @lc. Thank you. Yeah, that will be my next step.